# cx_Oracle - See Server Message After Execution

Tags: oracle, cx-oracle

If I run something like

```
delete from mytable where (...)
```

I will receive a message along the lines of `X rows deleted`.

How can I catch this message in python/cx_Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the messages produced by SQL*Plus, those are produced by the SQL*Plus application itself and are not available from the Oracle Client libraries.

Instead , you can produce the messages yourself by examining the attribute cursor.rowcount as in the following code:

```
cursor.execute("delete from TestStrings where rownum <= 5")
print(cursor.rowcount, "rows deleted")
```

Comment: I am interested in getting the message received in general, not just the number of rows deleted in this particular case.

Comment: I have updated the comment to indicate these messages come from the SQL*Plus application itself and not from the Oracle Client libraries.